# Gradle task to package a springboot project to ear

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle, ear

I want to package the [springboot restful webservice project](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)
into a ear file with gradle having a file structure like this:

--META-INF
-application.xml
--app.war

Please help me with the gradle task to achieve this.

Comment: There is a spring-boot gradle plugin which will package your project as a fat jar, which you can run.  Why do you need to package it as an ear?  and if you need it packaged as an ear, why a do you need to use spring-boot?

Comment: I want to deploy the EAR on Websphere Application Server under JDK 1.6 in one environment and on Tomcat (with uber Jar) under JDK 1.8 on another environment. This is the project requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle provides an ear plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ear_plugin.html

This should package as an ear.

Gradle also provides a spring-boot plugin:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html

Which will package as a runnable jar.